# How to add Error handling with User Claims Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to add some error-handling so when a user tries to hit an endpoint with an incorrect bearer token it will give the user some feedback with a error message instead of a blank error message. I've tried to implement it using an if statement in the controller but it doesn't seem to be hitting it.

I've attached my current response.

[image]

```
         public async Task<IActionResult> PostVenues(VenueRequest request)
        {
            var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "UserID").Value;

            if (userId == null)
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("User is not authorized");
```

Comment: You have to catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException` and return an appropriate `IActionResult` that displays the message to the user.

Comment: so I have to use a try catch instead?

Comment: That would be the test-friendly way to do it, imo. But to keep it simple you could also return the `IActionResult` after checking if the userId is null, with the appropriate message.

Comment: I've tried to setup a try catch but it's not evening catching the exception for some reason

Comment: @rey123, try `return StatusCode(401, "User is not authorized");`